# how to use Autoincrement javascript

Tags: javascript, php, jquery

I'm creating input text dynamically when i press a Enter key this is my code

[DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/8mw2q5tv/3/)

if i press the enter key on **strHtml5**, it will call the function **mostrarSalto()** and will create the other input list this is my table1 on it the input list will be created

well now my problem, i have an Autoincrement on each dinamically input text, this is becouse when i type on the **strHtml1** it will call a function called **buscar1()** this function is an instant search, when i type in the input this automatically find a coincidence and print it in the other inputs, this is the function **buscar1()**

```
function buscar1() {

    var textoBusqueda1 = $("input#ArtInput"+idd).val();

     if (textoBusqueda1 != "") {
        $.post("buscar1.php", {valorBusqueda1: textoBusqueda1}, function(mensaje1) {
            $("#resultadoBusqueda1").html(mensaje1);
         }); 
     } else { 
        $("#resultadoBusqueda1").html('<p>JQUERY VACIO</p>');
        $("input#a"+idd).val('');
        $("input#b"+idd).val('');
        $("input#c"+idd).val('');
        $("input#d"+idd).val('');
        };
};
```

and this is **buscar1.php**

```
<script src="js/jquery-1.12.3.min.js"></script>
<?php
//Archivo de conexión a la base de datos
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
error_reporting(E_ALL);


/* Connect using SQL Server Authentication. */    

$conn = mssql_connect(' ', ' ', '');    
mssql_select_db('PRUEBA',$conn);

//Variable de búsqueda
$consultaBusqueda1 = $_POST['valorBusqueda1'];


$mensaje1 = "";

if (isset($consultaBusqueda1)) {

    //Selecciona todo de la tabla mmv001 
    //donde el nombre sea igual a $consultaBusqueda, 
    //o el apellido sea igual a $consultaBusqueda, 
    //o $consultaBusqueda sea igual a nombre + (espacio) + apellido
    $consulta1 = mssql_query("SELECT * FROM REGISTROS WHERE ARTICULO LIKE '%$consultaBusqueda1%'");
    echo $consulta1;
    //Obtiene la cantidad de filas que hay en la consulta
    $filas1 = mssql_num_rows($consulta1);

    //Si no existe ninguna fila que sea igual a $consultaBusqueda, entonces mostramos el siguiente mensaje
    if ($filas1 === 0) {
        $mensaje1 = "<p>NOT FOUND</p>";

    } else {
        //Si existe alguna fila que sea igual a $consultaBusqueda, entonces mostramos el siguiente mensaje

        //La variable $resultado contiene el array que se genera en la consulta, así que obtenemos los datos y los mostramos en un bucle
        while($resultados1 = mssql_fetch_array($consulta1)) {

            $Art1 = $resultados1['ARTICULO'];
            $Cant1 = $resultados1['CANTIDAD'];
            $Impor1 = $resultados1['IMPORTE'];
            $Desc1 = $resultados1['DESCUENTO'];
            $Iva1 = $resultados1['IVA'];
            echo $Art1;

    ?>
            <script type="text/javascript">
            document.getElementById("a"+idd).value = '<?php echo $Cant1 ?>';
            document.getElementById("b"+idd).value = '<?php echo $Impor1 ?>';
            document.getElementById("c"+idd).value = '<?php echo $Desc1 ?>';
            document.getElementById("d"+idd).value = '<?php echo $Iva1 ?>';
            </script>
            <?php



        };//Fin while $resultados

    }; //Fin else $filas

};//Fin isset $consultaBusqueda

//Devolvemos el mensaje que tomará jQuery


?>
```

my problem is the autoincrement in the dinamically input text **ID** it works ok but whn i type in the **strHtml1** the function buscar1() is called only in the last input text but if i try to call it in a prev input this not work.

For example i have 5 rows of inputs, if i type in the 5th row the function is called ok, but if i type in the 4th row the function doesn't work.

Any ideas? Thank you.

Comment: Please use the "edit" link on your post to provide a [***minimal***, complete, verifiable example](/help/mcve). Walls of code make for questions that are too narrow and thus not useful to others in the future; they're also much less likely to get useful answers.

Comment: Your question is not quite clear, but it seems like you might want to use [event delegation](http://api.jquery.com/on/#direct-and-delegated-events) for your event handlers. Oh, and jQuery's [`.clone()`](http://api.jquery.com/clone/) method might save you some time as well.