# The right form to do this

Tags: javascript

i have this

```
var strHtml1 = document.createElement("Input")
strHtml1 = "<INPUT TYPE=\"text\" ID=\"ArtInput"+idd+"\" class=\"example\" NAME=\"h"+"[]\" SIZE=\"20\" MAXLENGTH=\"30\" onKeyPress=\"getId(this)\"  onkeyUp=\"buscar1(this);\" autofocus STYLE=\"height:22;border: 1 solid;margin:0;\">";
```

and i want to call it using

```
document.getElementById("ArtInput");
```

i know the correct form is

```
document.getElementById("ArtInput"+idd);
```

idd is an autoincrement

suppose we have 100 inputs text ID will be ArtInput1 , ArtInput2 , ArtInput3 , ..., ArtInput100

if i use

```
var x = document.getElementById("ArtInput"+idd);
alert(x.id);
```

my result will be ArtInput100,

how to manipulate which input is called?

Comment: Please can you clarify what you are asking? it is unclear.

Comment: Please use a more descriptive title, too.

Comment: Do you want to get all elements that you created that way? If yes you can search by class: `document.querySelectorAll('.example')`. If not, please clarify what you want.

Comment: We really need to see more context of the application, to understand what you're trying to do. Why are you trying to select a specific input without knowing its ID?

Comment: I was in this publication i was more clearer but I think I can not express myself in such a way that you can understand what i mean , I am also learning the language

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37306133/how-to-use-autoincrement-javascript

Answer (score 0):

Use a different variable, rather than `idd`, since, as you said, `idd` is auto-incremented and ends at 100.

For example:

```
var artInputIndex = 5;
var artInput = document.getElementById("ArtInput" + artInputIndex);
```